# Why does this code behave differently on 64 bit builds? (iOS / UIColor / UIKeyedArchiver)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, nscoding

**The code:**

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.3 saturation:0.2 brightness:0.2 alpha:1];
CGFloat r,g,b,a;

[color getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];

NSData * colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
UIColor * unarchivedColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];

[unarchivedColor getRed:&r green:&g blue:&b alpha:&a];
```

As expected on 32 bit builds, unarchivedColor and color have exactly the same rgb values. On arm64 builds, unarchivedColor and color start to differ around the 9th decimal place.

In other words, archiving/unarchiving a UIColor modifies the color on arm64... I need this not to happen. What's going on here and is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Confirmed via an Apple Technical support incident that this is a bug relating to the archiving class on arm64. Their suggestion was to build a custom archiver class instead.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is probably because on 32-bit, `CGFloat` is a `float` while under 64-bit it is a `double`.

Try using `double` instead of `CGFloat`. Or just accept the fact that under 64-bit, you will get higher precision values.

Comment: It's a UIColor object, so I don't have control over internal double/CGFloat properties. I'd rather not rewrite the whole UIColor class. Also - I can't just accept it, as every time a color is saved, it's value gets modified slightly. This doesn't cause a crash in my application, but it does result in a bug. I don't think it's unreasonable for code to assume that on normal circumstances, if an object gets saved and then opened again, it's going to be the same as it was beforehand... not behaving like this would indicate a problem?

Comment: But you have control over using `CFGloat`, `float`, or `double` for your `r,g,b,a` variables. You could also choose to archive the 4 separate values instead of `UIColor`.

Comment: I'm just looking at the r g b values to figure out what is wrong. It's the UIColor object that is being archived. Doing what you suggest assumes a constant color space, and for me it means changing the data structure of the app which isn't just a trivial task.

Comment: I don't know much about this, but maybe writing my own 64 bit safe implementation of NSCoding for UIColor would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue (or perhaps never was an issue).

```
UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithHue:0.3 saturation:0.2 brightness:0.2 alpha:1];
NSData * colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:color];
UIColor * unarchivedColor = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];

CGFloat r, g, b, h, s, a;
[color getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];
NSLog(@"HSBA %f %f %f %f", h, s, b, a);
[unarchivedColor getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&b alpha:&a];
NSLog(@"unarchived HSBA %f %f %f %f", h, s, b, a);

[color getRed:&r green:&r blue:&b alpha:&a];
NSLog(@"RGB %f %f %f %f", r, g, b, a);
[unarchivedColor getRed:&r green:&r blue:&b alpha:&a];
NSLog(@"unarchived RGB %f %f %f %f", r, g, b, a);
```

Results (formatted)

```
HSBA            0.300000 0.200000 0.200000 1.000000
unarchived HSBA 0.300000 0.200000 0.200000 1
RGB             0.200000 0.000000 0.160000 1.000000
unarchived RGB  0.200000 0.000000 0.160000 1.000000
```

**However**, constructing a `UIColor` object using HSBA values without `arm64` selected, archiving it, and then unarchiving it under `arm64` will result in different HSBA value when they are recovered due to different levels of precision with 64-bit.

Comment: It most certainly was an issue. Confirmed by an Apple Engineer that helped write that part of the framework, not just your default Apple Technical Support respondent. Good to know it's been fixed.